# How does JMeter includes own library written by JavaScript in BSF Assertion

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell

I use JavaScript to parse my JSON result in BSF Assertion.
For more reusability, i try to write my own JavaScript library. I would like use the library in my BSF Assertion.

Maybe i misunderstand the documents, i cannot find anyway to import my library in BSF.
Dose only BeanShell provide this kind of method to import external script?
(http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell)

I even try another way but in vain.

1.Create BSF PreProcessor and put my library (named: myScript) in it.

```
function test(){
    log.info("Test Library");
}
```

2.Import the code and invoke it,

```
${__BeanShell(vars.get("myScript"))};
test()
```

But it doesn't work .. :(

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by import library ? Include javascript external file ?

Comment: yes, i would like to include my own javascript library from external file.

Comment: Was my answer helpful ? if yes you should accept it so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSR223 PreProcessor
Choose Javascript language

Include your library using for example [__FileToString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)jsCode and put it in UserDefinedVariable:

```
jsCode / __FileToString(path to file)
```

In my example, file contains:

```
var s = "toto";
```

In you script:

```
${jsCode};
vars.put("toto", s);
```

Anyway I am not sure using Javascript is great for performances.

Groovy is a better option.

Comment: Hi, it works! Does this way will "replace" code when we need it? If i have a big javascript need to import but i might not call any function in it. It will put whole javascript into my runtime environment, so it will cause performances issue. Do we have another way to import javascript? Just like we import library in BeanShell. e.g., `import com.google.gson.*;` thanks!

Comment: Not with javascript, if it works you should accept the answer and upvote so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

With BSF Element, you could expose javascript functions too.
Check the example [JMeter-Load-Javascript-Libraries-For-Future-Usage](https://github.com/lifecube/JMeter-Load-Javascript-Libraries-For-Future-Usage)